# Writing a hashtable value to an attribute

Tags: powershell

Powershell newbie here, my first script.

I have user objects with an  AD custom  attribute named tvCode with a values of 123456 or 6787682 or 983736 etc.

I would like to script something that will get the tvCode value from the user object

```
   When:
           123456 = Sony 

           6787682 = Samsung

           9837343 = LG
```

Write the value of "Sony" or "Samsung" or "LG" to the "City" attribute of the user object.

Looks like i may need to use a hashtable.

If possible do this for a specific OU

hope this makes sense

thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what errors did it give you? There's a few ways to do this, but I think a hashtable would be the way I would go (even if it means missing a chance to preach about the under appreciated `Switch` cmdlet).

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SO is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

```
function Convert-TVCode {
    Param
    (
    [parameter(Mandatory=$true,Position=0,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
    [String[]]
    $Code
    )
    Process {
        foreach ($C in $Code) {
            switch ($C) {
                "123456" {$brand = "Sony"}
                "6787682" {$brand = "Samsung"}
                "9837343" {$brand = "LG"}
                default {
                    $brand = $null
                    Write-Warning "$C not included in switch statement. Returning"
                    return
                }
            }
            if ($brand) {
                Write-Verbose "Code '$C' matched to Brand '$brand' -- searching for users to update"
                Get-ADUser -Filter "tvCode -eq '$C'" | Set-ADUser -Replace @{tvCode=$brand}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This function will allow you to update any users that have their `tvCode` attribute set as one of the target numerical values. You can have it hit multiple codes at once as well.

Examples:

```
Convert-TVCode -Code 123456
Convert-TVCode -Code 123456,6787682
Convert-TVCode -Code 123456,6787682,9837343 -Verbose
```

Update the switch statement in the function to customize it to your actual values and let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: I will give it a try, much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: @mark-wragg thanks for the edit! totally forgot the Process block.

Comment: @lakeek let me know if you have any questions on the use (or errors) when trying this out!

Comment: Looks like I got it working on test attributes and test OU. Thank you. I would like to keep the code in tvCode and write "Sony" to another attribute ie. City.  I tried -Replace @{"l"=$brand}. that is not working. Amy ideas?

Comment: You can actually just use the `-City` parameter for that (`-Replace` is good for attributes which aren't represented in the parameter set)... You would update the Set-ADUser` command to this: `Get-ADUser -Filter "tvCode -eq '$C'" | Set-ADUser -City "$brand"`

Comment: It is working, thanks for your help. I was told this is not a coding service and I understand that. I just did not know where to start. New to powershell!!  I really appreciate your help. Thanks again.

Comment: No problem! You'll continue to grow on StackOverflow and get used to the way everything needs to work. I definitely recommend checking out the links that Jeff Zeitlin provided in his comment for a deeper dive on SO best practices!